# IP blocked after editing an answer

Tags: support, status-completed

Im trying to edit this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/664/whats-the-difference-between-a-projection-and-a-datum/665#665) by adding its sources like this:

**Source: Copy/Paste from Wikipedia:**

- [Map projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection)
- [Geodetic datum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodetic_datum)

but the edit was canceled 10 seconds after I push the button. I tryed to edit it again and then my IP was blocked from gis.stackexchange.com. I had to reinitialize it to be able to access the site again. Meanwhile, the edit was canceled again...

I think this is not a good thing for a serious site like this.

I wonder if my IP was blocked automatically or by a moderator?

Is it important to put the sources when you copy/paste info from other website? I think it is.

Comment: I reverted the answer. If the definitions were quoted from Wikipedia, I would agree that they should be attributed. As it is, I can find multiple documents with similar, but not exact, definitions. Which ones should be considered the source?

Comment: The premise of this edit seems frivolous to me. I would have rejected it as well. Unless you are the OP, or you found an exact quote, it does not seem proper, or polite, to attribute it to some other entity. At least ask for references in the comments and allow time for the OP to respond before making an edit.

Comment: @blah238 I don't think the purpose was frivolous at all: we *do* care about proper attribution here.  And the need for attribution is not limited to word-for-word exact quotations, either: when posted material is substantially the same as material previously published elsewhere, perhaps with small amounts of paraphrasing, then it is only right to provide an attribution.  When material appears in multiple places on the Web, it is correct to attribute *any* of the sources (even if they themselves do not own up to the fact of their own unoriginality!)

Comment: @whuber, I took exception to the "Copy/Paste" statement in the edit. That's implying quotation, not just attributing a source. But, yes, attribution should be made when possible, and hopefully by encouraging OP to do it!

Comment: After fixing the links in this Question I checked the linked Answer against the two Wikipedia pages cited and found nothing to suggest a copy/paste had been performed or even similar phraseology used.

Answer (score 7):

When you attempt to do something and it is rejected, it can annoy people and might be perceived as rude to keep repeating it.  If your IP was banned (which is unlikely; something else was probably going on) then that would be due to an automatic system response programmed to prevent precisely that kind of behavior.

When an attempted edit is rejected and you are convinced it is correct (and I personally agree in this case with the reason you gave, which is that quotations should be attributed), you have additional options which you ought to undertake in roughly this order:

- **Post a comment instead of an attempted edit,** encouraging the original poster to make the change.  This gives them an opportunity to reflect on the merits of your proposal--or to explain why it might not be appropriate.
- **Flag the post.**  In this case it's a matter of acknowledging sources and that is something moderators and the SE team are interested in, so flagging would likely be viewed as a legitimate action.  (Whether it is acted on or denied depends on the particular merits of the situation.)
- **Post your own counter-answer.**  This is getting pretty extreme--we don't want to conduct debates within the answers of a thread--but sometimes it works.
- **Raise a *general* issue here on Meta.**  But please do not attack the behavior of a particular individual if you can help it!  The key to being courteous and tactful, even when you are perfectly in the right, is to address *actions* and *issues* rather than people.

Comment: The edit was canceled like 10 secondes after I press the button. I juste thought it was not saved in the system. Anyway, I dont have time to lose fighting against moderator.

Comment: I hope I was clear: you and I are not fighting about anything.  I am trying to persuade you that you should not be fighting about anything at all!  I am also hoping you will modify your post to remove references to specific individuals.  If not, it will be difficult to keep it open and public.  Please review the [system's guidance on good behavior](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).

Comment: My IP was banned by the author of the answer who is a moderator. You can imagine he did not want people to know his answer was copy/pasted from wikipedia.

Comment: (1) The author of that answer is not a moderator.  (2) Moderators do not have the power to block IP addresses--even the SE team itself is very reluctant to do that. We do have the power to suspend users, but that does not happen until a long process of communication with the user has been carried out. (3) Please do not speculate in public about people's motivations: just address the issues you are having with the site and how it works.

Comment: Please be careful. Statements like "The game you are playing ..." and "..do not speculate in public about people's motivations.." can seem a little bit contradictory/hypocritical. When the OP says "I just thought it was not saved in the system." i believe he was not playing a game, merely trying to finish what he started, in an honest and constructive manner. Remember that it takes a long time for users to become fully aware of how things work, both in terms of mechanics and etiquette.

Comment: A very similar thing happened a few weeks ago to me and you: I was busily adding the [cogo] tag and description -- not all at once because ideas came to me in stages. I was completely unaware of what was happening "at the other end" until some days later when i happened upon the edit history. You were editing, and re-editing, my work and noted (perhaps with a little frustration) an "again" in the remark section. I felt like "phoning" you to appologise at the time. If i thought i was perceived as "playing a game", i might have actually done so (appologised), if i knew how ;-)

Comment: @martin f I understand this looks weird and I probably should change it (I just did: thank you), but please see the edit history to the question in order to understand my original first sentence: it responds directly to what the OP wrote.  (You will have to go back to the first two versions.)  It was not my own phrase.

Comment: I see, yes, it definitely needed toning down, and a good answer!